# Why do I get a KeyError if I try to print certain columns of a CSV file given their indices?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to parse a CSV file in Python. This is what I have so far.

```
import csv
import os

csv_file_path = r'C:\Users\ctumbs\OneDrive\General - Vision Dataset\numbers.csv'


with open(csv_file_path) as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    for row in reader:
        print(row[0], row[2], row[4], row[6])
```

Right now I get an error that says 'KeyError: 0'.

When I replace the row indices and just have my last line as `print(row)`, I'm able to generate output, but there are too many columns. Here's an example of my output:

```
39431   568404   5849392
34783   383392   4933983
02941   848292   3820201
38493   283293   3929300
```

Comment: Since you're using `DictReader`, why are you using the indices instead of the names?

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm not following that output. Why are there only three columns? Shouldn't the rows be dicts with at least 7 items?

Answer (score 1):

[`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) returns one dictionary for each row, where the column headers are used as keys.

"KeyError: 0" means that there is no column which is named "0".

If you want to select columns by their index instead of the header, use a [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) instead, which returns one list for each row.